# Copy WebSQL database to another location

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a big WebSQL database in my app (up to 200 MB) and would like to offer a backup functionality. Is there a way to copy the whole database from the default location to another? I already have an JSON export, but it takes 5 minutes to export all data. It's not handy for daily backups :(

happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The database is (on android) in path

```
file://data/data/<packageName>/app_database/<dbname>.db
```

You can copy the file from there with phonegap's copyTo method. Before restoring I try to close the database by doing

```
delete myDatabaseObject;
```

After that you can use the copyTo method to overwrite the existing db. Finally it has to be opened like common.

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C makes a mention of the LOAD INPUT FILE](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), but says there's no reason to support it in WebSQL.

The nature of a WebSQL database is that it exists in the browser. If you can write a method to export your database into a JSON file, why not write a script that will recreate the database from the JSON file?

Comment: The nature of WebSQL is changed when it's used in a cordova app. Exporting to JSON works but costs a lot of time especially if the database contains binary data (base64). The same problem while loading data.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question that has an accepted answer regarding webSQL paths, but I was in a similar situation recently and examined a couple of different Android devices while running a Cordova app. Someone might find it helpful to know other db paths are being used.  While running Android 11, one was:
file://data/data/<pkg_name>/app_webview/Default/databases/https_localhost_0/1

and another (Android 4.4 kitkat) was:
file://data/data/<pkg_name>/app_webview/databases/files__0/1

Running on nw.js under Windows, the db was at: C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\<app_name>\databases\file__0\1

The db file is named "1" without an extension in all cases I checked, "files__0" has two underline chars. Hopefully, this answer will help someone out.